# Authentication problem on android with Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-ad-msal

I am using the ADD/B2C authentication system (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) in 3 different Xamarin applications on Android, and it happens when I try to log, after entering the credentials does not redirects me to the application that called it.

I have removed all the apps and I try with just one and it works fine, but if I have all 3 at the same time installed on the phone then it happens that it redirects me to any other than the one trying to log in.

Possibly a misplaced configuration.

Pd: In UWP that problem does not happen ...

I'm using the nuget: Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sure that the issue is with the redirect URL, So how this works is MSAL to return back to your specific application expects a redirect URL that you enter in your AndroidManifest file as mention here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c#register-your-mobile-application-with-azure-active-directory-b2c

All you have to do is make sure that all the three applications have the correct ApplicationId and that the redirect URL is correct in all three.

Revert in case if it still does not work

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will try and tell you if I could solve it.

Comment: Sure let me know if you face any issues

Comment: @FreakyAli  I am not able to get the access token in my xamarin.forms android application. The sample is working fine though. Basically its not returning the auth result in the below code. It is taking me to interactive sign in everytime. Any help ?

 AuthenticationResult authResult = await PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(B2CConstants.Scopes)
                .WithAccount(GetAccountByPolicy(accounts, B2CConstants.PolicySignUpSignIn))
                .WithParentActivityOrWindow(ParentActivityOrWindow)
                .ExecuteAsync();

Comment: Have you set the correct return URL in your Android Manifest

Comment: Sorry, I was not setting up SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs() its working fine now. Thank you.

Comment: Sure my pleasure!